# how to extract 2nd and fifth row of data in everyday in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame name df, I want to extract every 2nd and 5th row of the data for every day and put it into a new data frame. How should I do that? The time for my data is already in `pd.to_datatime` format.
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post sample data? not as image.

Comment: I see you posed a different situation to jezrael, which involves another column.. you should really take the time to explain every complication in your original question, as a courtesy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.nth`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html) by dates extracted by [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(df['Datetime'].dt.date).nth([2,5])
```

Or if need original not changed data use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter and compare by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html), but subtract `1` because python counts from `0` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.groupby(df['Datetime'].dt.date).cumcount().isin([1,4])]
```

Comment: let said it I have another column as employee, how should I avoid to pick the same employee for the 2nd and 5th row?

Comment: So if the 2nd row's employee is the same as 5th row's employee, how to choose the next  row?

Comment: @Elvis - Not so easy, can you change data for see this problem? I think [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but in text for possible copy data.